# Why is the default case matched in this switch statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I've got a question about `switch` statements.
Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float a=0.0f;
  float b=0.0f;
  char operation=0;

  printf("Enter expression:");
  scanf("%f %c %f",&a,&operation,&b);

    switch(operation)
    {
      case '+':
      printf("=%.2f\n",a+b);
      break;

      case '-':
      printf("=%.2f\n",a-b);
      break;

      case '*':
      printf("=%.2f\n",a*b);
      break;

      case '/':
      if(b==0)
      printf("\ndivision by zero error.\n");
      else
      printf("=%.2f\n",a/b);
      break;

      case '%':
      if(b==0)
      printf("\ndivision by zero error.\n");
      else
      printf("=%d\n",(int)a%(int)b);
      break;

      default:
      printf("invalid operation\n");
      break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is result about two different input, one right, one wrong.

[image: my output]

Why, when I enter two letters instead of two numbers, does it go into the `default` case?

Comment: Please do not post links to images of text. Please post the text.

Comment: What's the value of `operation`? Did you debug your code?

Comment: You try to save characters into floats so scanf will not match and since operation is initialized to 0 therefore the default case will execute.

Comment: You ignore the return  value of `scanf()` at your own risk.

Comment: Why don't you print out the values of `a`, `b` and `operation` before the switch - then you will probabaly see what's happening.

Comment: @AdrianMole ... and the return value of scanf for good measure.

Comment: Thank you all your help, i understand now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a+b` won't match the format string of your `scanf` since it expects floats not chars (like `a` or `b`), therefore `scanf` does not do anything.

`scanf` returns the number of items it was able to read which will be 0 in this case. Checking its return value is not a bad idea.

And since `operation` is initialized to `0` the default case will execute.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%f %c %f",&a, &operation, &b);`

So, when you enter **a+b**:

1. 'a' is not a `float`
2. [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) fails (you can check this by looking at its return value)
3. `operation` is still with its default value which is `0`

Inside the switch statement, none of the cases('+', '-', '*', '/', '%') get matched because `char operation = 0;`

Therefore, the default block is executed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand now.. I don’t think of that, too lazy.. really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to check the return value of scanf

```
// scanf("%f %c%f", &a, &operation, &b);
if (scanf("%f %c%f", &a, &operation, &b) != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to convert input!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: I find it! Thank you for your help